# Use of Extern keyword

Tags: c++, extern

I am familiar with the extern keyword, it is used to declare a variable present in some other file, but what does the following statement mean??

```
extern "C" const IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern "C"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)

Comment: Wnat is `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`?  Language linkage normally only applies to function types (included nested function types, such as pointer to function).

Comment: @James, global variable names [are mangled too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2937273/464709). Your point about linkage having further effect on functions still stands, though.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Mangling is up to the implementation; it may mangle nothing, everything or anything in between.  In practice, most compilers, for most languages, have mangled everything; what has traditionally set C++ apart is the complexity of the mangling scheme (including information concerning the types of parameters) for functions.  Traditionally, C and C++ have mangled variable names in the same manner.  (A quick check with the compilers I have handy show that after `extern "C"`, I can't even find the name in the object file.  Which I definitely don't understand.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means do not mangle the symbol name `__ImageBase` that follows the `extern "C"`. In short it ensures you can use the variable in C++ code.

`extern "C"` specify's the linkage to be applied. In short a Linkage specification.
It tells the C++ compiler to apply linkage of the type of C to the symbol that follows.

Good Read:
**[Using extern to Specify Linkage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**
**[How to mix C and C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html)**

Comment: The now-deleted comment was right, as `extern "C"` is indeed a C++-only construct, but it still means C code that links to the C++ module defining this variable will be able to refer to it... So, it actually works both ways, C to C++ and C++ to C (section 32.6 of the FAQ seems to agree :).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi:  A C compiler won't understand the `extern "C"` construct, and so one must wrap the `extern "C" {` and` }` lines in an `#ifdef` so they won't be seen by the C compilers.

Comment: Yes, we agree that it cannot be used outside of C++ modules. But it both allows to use the decorated symbol if it is defined in a C module, or allows C modules to use the symbol if the C++ module itself defines it. That's what I meant by `both ways` (but I don't know if I was actually clearer this time around :)

Answer (score 5):

It means the `__ImageBase` global variable uses [C linkage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d.aspx) and that its name should be [mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) using the rules for C instead of C++.

**EDIT:** It just so happens that [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) recently published [an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/25/10310148.aspx) that demonstrates my original answer was plain wrong: `extern "C"` does not *disable* name mangling, it only *changes the rules* used to perform it. C names can be mangled too.

Comment: C linkage involves more than just mangling; it's possible for the arguments to be passed differently, for example.  Also, the language linkage is part of the type; a function with `extern "C"` linkage cannot be assigned to a pointer to a C++ function.