# failed to find entry point even though Dependency Walker says it's there

Tags: dll, dependency-walker

After launching my app, it complains that entry point glIsQuery could not be located. So I used Dependency Walker to debug this problem.

The Parent Import Function table does show that 'glIsQuery' is missing, as shown below

[image]

However, the Export Function List also shows that the symbol exists (I also used dumpbin to verify this)
[image]

Any clue?

Comment: Could this be a c++ name mangling issue?

Comment: Clearly they are not the same name, the name decoration matters.

Comment: @HansPassant from my understanding, the underscore and '@4' in the second image indicates the calling convention is __stdcall. what would you suggest to solve my problem?

Comment: @ken both my program and the dll are pure C

Comment: @user11869 - But what is compiling them? C++ compiler or C compiler?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the name `_glIsQuery@4` was decorated (or mangled) by a C++ compiler. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2937273/651789) (and particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2937313/651789) that gives a pretty close example).

You may need an `extern "C"` if you want to use `glIsQuery`.