# Calling C++ class functions in C file using extern "C"

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to use `extern "C"` to be able to call a C++ class within a different C file. I can build this fine until I actually include the `.h` in the C file I want to call the C++ class from.

**MyClass.cpp**

```
MyClass::MyClass(){};
MyClass::~MyClass(){};

extern "C" void* MyClassInit(){
    return new MyClass();
}
```

**MyClass.h**

```
extern "C" void* MyClassInit();
```

OK - the above compiles. But now I want to use `MyClassInit` in another `.c` file. As soon as I

`#include "MyClass.h"` in that file I get

`error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant` in `MyClass.h` where the externs are defined.

I assume I am missing some "if cplusplus" or another extern or something else very obscure.

Comment: Missing ; in header???

Comment: IINM you need to remove the `extern "C"` from the C side. The easiest way is to make it a macro that is toggled by `#ifdef __cplusplus`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no `extern "C"` in C: a C compiler won't understand this and will choke on it. You need to expose this directive to the C++ compiler only. This is why often in such headers you find this instead (a random example e.g. [here](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/zlib.h)):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

... code ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The C preprocessor will remove the `extern "C"`, keeping the enclosed code only, while for the C++ compiler, the same file will look like

```
extern "C" {
... code ...
}
```

**Update:** A few words on the purpose of the whole `extern "C"` construct, and why it only appears in C++, as suggested by Justin Randall in the comments. Perhaps the leading reason why this is needed is that it prevents [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). This is important when overloaded functions of the same name exist: mangled names are made unique, so these can be distinguished. On the other hand, there is no overloading in C, so no name mangling either and no need for the `extern` block.

Long story short, a typical C++ compiler would tend to rename a function like `void f()`, for example, to something like `_Z1fv`. But the C compiler would look for `f` and fail. `extern "C"` makes the former use the same symbol name the latter would expect.

More precise information can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage).

Comment: Oh wow.. I finally understand this block of code that's littered throughout my codebase :) Thank you. Just to ask - does the `extern "C"` need to be present in the .cpp file?

Comment: Nice concise answer to a good question.  It's also worth mentioning that `extern "C" { }` is simply telling the C++ compiler not to [mangle the function names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937273/questions-about-name-mangling-in-c), which is why a C compiler will choke on it.