# Why name-mangling has no effect on main function in C++?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, name-mangling

C++ compiler often mangle function names to support many features. Programer can suppress default name-mangling using **extern "C"** way. However, why `int main(int, char **)` not affected ever?

```
// test.cpp

int max(int a, int b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

extern "C" {
    int min(int a, int b) {
        return a < b ? a : b;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

And

```
$  xcrun --sdk macosx clang -x c++ -c test.cpp -o test  
$  xcrun nm -nm test  

0000000000000000 (__TEXT,__text) external __Z3maxii  
0000000000000030 (__TEXT,__text) external _min  
0000000000000060 (__TEXT,__text) external _main
```

Obviously, `int max(int, int)` is mangled to `__Z3maxii`; `int min(int int)` is free from mangling with **extern "C"** annotation.

How does main escape from mangling?
Is there any way else to keep name from mangling except the above annotation?

Comment: Is it inconceivable that the compiler makes an exception for this one?

Comment: There's no need to mangle `main`: it is UB to define anything with the name `main` unless it is `int main()` xor `int main(int, char**)`.

Comment: out of curiosity: why do you care?

Comment: Say `main` doesn't have to explicitly return anything, and nobody cares. Don't mangle its name, and people start losing their mind :)

Comment: Not much. Just curious. @user463035818

Answer (score 8):

Per [`[basic.start.main]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#1.sentence-1), [`[basic.start.main]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2.sentence-2) and [`[over]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over#1.sentence-1):

> A program shall contain a global function called `main`. [...] This function shall not be overloaded. [...] When two or more different declarations are specified for a single name in the same scope, that name is said to be *overloaded* [...].

This is then undefined behavior to have anything in the global namespace with the name `main`. There is then no reason for an implementation to mangle `main` or even consider it to be a proper function.

Answer (score 6):

Name mangling is a process used by C++ compilers to give each function in your program a unique name. In C++, generally programs have at-least a few functions with the same name ie function overloading, however Main is special, its actually a global function of the C language that can never be overloaded, so it is not necessary.

Take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

And [questions about name mangling in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937273/questions-about-name-mangling-in-c)

(Main) special properties

> It cannot be predefined and cannot be overloaded: effectively, the name main in the global namespace is reserved for functions (although it can be used to name classes, namespaces, enumerations, and any entity in a non-global namespace, except that a function called "main" cannot be declared with C language linkage in any namespace (since C++17))