# problem with compiling a simple program with c++

Tags: c++

I am really new to C++. I am trying to compile this simple program but I get an error

```
#include <iostream> 
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
   cout << "You have entered " << argc 
        << " arguments:" << "\n"; 
 
   for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) 
       cout << argv[i] << "\n"; 
 
   return 0; 
}
```

The error that I get is

```
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I try to compile it as g++ file1.cpp
I also tried
g++ -c file1.cpp and then g++ main.exe file1.o
which does not work as well.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This error should not occur provided that you *really* have the `main` function in `file1.cpp`. If, for example, you named it `Main` for some reason, you will see exactly this error. Please double check the contents of your `file1.cpp` file.

Comment: The selected answer is considered bad practice, and shouldn't even be capable of fixing your issue. There is missing information here. I would have expected a different error for the code you're showing.

Comment: instead of using using namespace std; at the start I added std whenever it was needed. For example std::cout

Comment: I believe the whole question should be deleted. I think the reason for the link error is somehow lost in changes to the code that happened after the error occurred. This code does have a compile error but that should not have given the link error.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You can try specify namespace like this ->

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

EDIT 'must' replaced by 'can try'. It works but why !

Comment: This is completely irrelevant for the issue mentioned in the question.

Comment: The moment I added using namespace it compiled just fine! Thank you

Comment: Ok @Alex so approve the answer

Comment: Now, I am courious how a missing `using namespace std;` can lead to a link time error as shown in the question ... are you sure that you have not modified something else in addition?

Comment: OP is not giving all the information is how. This answer is bogus, and a bad practice.

Comment: Is it possible that the `.o` file was generated from a previous build? Or does gcc delete it if the current compile of a single file fails? I am talking about the case of `g++ -c file1.cpp` followed by `g++ main.exe file1.o`

Comment: I gess if the line using namespace std; is removed the error occur again.

Comment: @drescherjm OP claimed that even the all-in-one execution of `g++ file1.cpp`  raised this error

Comment: I know, I don't understand that.

Comment: @Florent I would then expect a different (compile time) error like `error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: Agreed this should have had a compile time error not a linker error about ***undefined reference to `main'***

Comment: Perhaps the signature of main ? --> int main (int argc, char *argv[])

Comment: That is equivalent.

Comment: And even if it was not, it should not affect `main()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53393585/why-name-mangling-has-no-effect-on-main-function-in-c

Comment: This is bad advice and "must" is wrong. It will also not fix the error OP is asking about. Read this: 
[Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: 'must' replaced by 'can try'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try and create a new file in an empty directory name it if you want something like main.cpp  and put the code in that you needed for namespace and everything else and run

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    int main(int argc, char** argv) 
        { 
           cout << "You have entered " << argc 
                << " arguments:" << "\n"; 
         
           for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) 
               cout << argv[i] << "\n"; 
         
           return 0; 
        }
```

It should work after and output a result
Maybe check out this medium article for more about why you need using namespace std
https://medium.com/breaktheloop/why-using-namespace-std-is-used-after-including-iostream-dc5ae45db652