# lex.yy.c is not getting linked with external functions

Tags: c, linker, lex

I am writing an SQL parser. `SQLSelectParser.l` is the lex file which generates `lex.yy.c` file successfully using lex compiler. In `SQLSelectParser.l` file, I call external functions defined in `Ast.h/c` file. I #include Ast.h in %{  %} section of `SQLSelectParser.l`.

I compiles the src file individually without any problems.

```
lex SQLSelectParser.l
gcc -g -c lex.yy.c -o lex.yy.o
gcc -g -c Ast.c -o Ast.o 
gcc -g lex.yy.o Ast.o -o exe -lfl   << but get linker error.
```

Function `ast_add_child` is declared in Ast.h and defined in Ast.c. I am not able to understand why i am getting linker error. **Is this common problem while linking with flex generated src file ?**

```
/usr/bin/ld: lex.yy.o: in function `create_q_parse_columns':
/home/vm/RDBMSImplementation/Parsers/SQLSelectParser.l:405: undefined reference to `ast_add_child'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/vm/RDBMSImplementation/Parsers/SQLSelectParser.l:417: undefined reference to `ast_add_child'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

here is a link to [SQLSelectParser.l file](https://github.com/sachinites/RDBMSImplementation/blob/main/Parsers/SQLSelectParser.l) which used ast_add_child().

[Ast.h is here](https://github.com/sachinites/RDBMSImplementation/blob/main/Parsers/Ast.h)

[Ast.cpp is here](https://github.com/sachinites/RDBMSImplementation/blob/main/Parsers/Ast.cpp)

Comment: Note that if you provide your own `main()` function then `-lfl` does nothing useful for you.  But neither is it harmful.

Comment: Supposing that lex.yy.c compiled cleanly at normal or enhanced warning level, the issue is probably in your Ast.c: it does not provide an external definition of function `ast_add_child()`.  Possibly it provides an internal (`static`) one instead, possibly it provides the function with a different (misspelled) name, or possibly it just doesn't provide the function at all.

Comment: no, functions are public in Ast.h/.c. , not static.

Comment: That was only one of the possible issues I mentioned.  Without a [mre] we can only suggest possibilities, but I assure you that the issue has nothing to do with `flex`.  The linker error is telling you, among other things, that Ast.o is not providing `ast_add_child` as an external function.  Look for the function's definition (implementation) in Ast.c.  If you find it then correct the spelling of its name there, and / or make sure it's not carrying any function attributes that might be interfering, and / or ensure that it's not being excluded by conditional compilation directives.

Comment: And if you have not already done so then *confirm*, too, that it is not defined with the `static` qualifier.

Comment: And make sure that Ast.c `#include`s Ast.h.  That will help the compiler recognize some (but not all) errors related to declarations mismatched with their definitions.  And turn on at least the `-Wall` compiler option, and maybe also one or both of `-Wextra` and `-pedantic`.

Comment: Added Ast.h/.cpp if you want to take a look. @john

Comment: since you have a .cpp file mentioned I'm curious if you are actually trying to compile a c function into a c++ application without the use of an `extern "C"` block

Comment: No, I do not want to take a look at an external resource.  Everything needed to inform an answer to the question needs to be presented in the question itself.  Preferably in the form of a [mre].

Comment: However, your link betrays a relevant detail that you previously disguised: you do not have an Ast.c file, but rather Ast.cpp.  This would conventionally indicate a file intended for compilation as C++, and if it is indeed being compiled that way, without provision for being its functions being C-callable, then that would be another plausible explanation.

Comment: Though file Ast.cpp is named with cpp extention, it contain purely C code. I was using gcc to compile. However, linking time it was throwing error as i mentioned. I renamed Ast.cpp to Ast.c and linker error immediately goes away. I thought as long as file contain pure C code, file extension dont matter to compilers. Thanks for your time and effort @JohnBollinger

Comment: C++ uses name mangling unless you specifically tell it not to. This is a thing you have to always be wary of when linking C and C++. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937273/questions-about-name-mangling-in-c

Comment: ... and some compilers and build systems *do* pay attention to filename extension, though I'm not used to GCC doing this when run explicitly.  And I have no clue why one would name a source file .cpp when one means for it to be interpreted as C code.  C and C++ are distinct languages with a shared subset.  If you are exceedingly careful, you can write code that is *source* compatible with both, but even then it can matter how you compile it, as you discovered.

Answer (score 1):

> `gcc -g -c Ast.c -o Ast.o`

Rule 1: show *actual* command instead of imaginary one.

You don't have `Ast.c`, you have `Ast.cpp`, so the command you've shown must not be the command you actually ran.

When you compile code with `gcc -c Ast.cpp`, it gets compiled as `C++`. If you run `nm Ast.o | grep ast_add_child`, you would see something like `_Z13ast_add_childv`.

Rule 2: learn to fish. When you get an undefined symbol error, use `nm` (as above) to *confirm* the symbol you are missing is *in fact* defined where you think it is.